# TypeError: string indices must be integers and ValueError

Tags: python, typeerror

I want to iterate through the data and only download logins but I get this error:

```
print elem["login"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

My code:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import urllib

 def printContents(path):
    filein = open(path, 'r')
    instr = filein.read()
    filein.close()
 printContents("top_story_2012.txt")
 appkey = "...."
 url= "http://a.wykop.pl/ludzie/followers/"
 wykopff = open("top_story_2012.txt", 'r')
 names = [line.strip() for line in wykopff.readlines()]
 for i in names:
    p = urllib.urlopen(url + i + "/appkey/" + appkey)
    wykops = p.read()
    read = json.loads(wykops)
    for elem in wykops:
        print elem["login"]
```

I tried to change 'login' to an integer:

```
   print elem[int("login")]
```

I'm not sure if that's the way to do it but it still doesn't work and then I get this error:

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'login'
```

The content I am trying to iterate through looks like this:

```
  {"login":"Josif6969","email":"a9a4525e207fcba3ac0fc221246439a3:3670009297","public_email":"","name":"","www":"","jabber":"","gg":"","city":"","about":"Hobby: Obserwator.","author_group":1,"links_added":82,"links_published":4,"comments":132,"rank":0,"followers":
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `for elem in read`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop over `read`, the decoded JSON structure, instead:

```
wykops = p.read()
read = json.loads(wykops)
for elem in read:
    print elem["login"]
```

or, simplifying it to use `json.load()` instead:

```
for elem in json.load(p):
    print elem["login"]
```

This assumes that the data from the `json.load()` call is a list though, I think you simply wanted to treat the result as a dictionary instead:

```
data = json.load(p):
print data["login"]
```

It sounds (from the comments) as if *some* of the responses return a list instead. Try this to figure out what is going on:

```
data = json.load(p):
try:
    print data["login"]
except TypeError:
    # not a dictionary, so what is it *then*?
    print "Not a dictionary:", data
```

Your code was looping over the JSON data string instead, character by character, so you were trying to apply `["login"]` to a python string:

```
>>> 'somestring'["login"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Yes true, I need to loop over read but I still get: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @user2015906: Try the second suggestion; if `read` is a dictionary, looping over it gives you the *keys* of the dictionary, and `elem` is then still a string.

Comment: @user2015906: use `read['login']`, *no* loop. Or replace what you just put into your comment with my *second* example (`data = json.load(p); print data['login']`) which does the same in fewer lines.

Comment: wykops = p.read() data = json.load(p) print data['login'] Gives an error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @user2015906: Remove the `wykops = p.read()` line. `.load()` reads the data for you, but you cannot read it twice.

Comment: This time it brings up this: KeyError: 'login'

Comment: @user2015906: Then there is no `login` key in your returned data. How about you use `print` a little more? `print data` would give you an idea as to what kind of information is returned.

Comment: Now that I have access to the API I receive this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @user2015906: So, `data` is now a list? *Then* you can do `for elem in data`.

Comment: I just applied your second suggestion and it seems that in print data['login'] data it read as a list?

Comment: @user2015906: Please insert a `print data` right after the `json.load()` and Python will *tell* what you have. You are making stabs in the dark here otherwise.

Comment: The output I get with print data is as stated in my questions: {"login":"Josif6969","email":"a9a4525e207fcba3ac0fc221246439a3:3670009297"} and so on....

Comment: @user2015906: If that is exactly what you get then `print data['login']` should work, but it sounds as if *some* responses give you a list instead.